# Disabling one keyword in minted

Tags: minted

I'm formatting SQL code in my document using [`minted`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf):

```
\usepackage{minted}
\newmintedfile[sql]{sql}{breaklines=true,samepage,fontsize=\footnotesize}

% ...

\sql{query.sql}
```

In some of these files I'm using `source` as the name of a column, but minted recognises it as a keyword. In my SQL dialect this is fine though.

Is there a simple way I can disable `source` as a keyword in minted?

---

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\newmintedfile[sql]{sql}{breaklines=true,tabsize=4,samepage,frame=none,fontsize=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\sql{query.sql}

\end{document}
```

And the SQL for in query.sql:

```sql
SELECT 
    schedule,
    cost
FROM 
    Schedule
WHERE
        source = 'x'
    AND
        destination = 'y';
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to change this on the TeX side, because `minted` delegates everything to Pygments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to patch the Pygments macros to do what you want.  The macros are of the form `\PYG<style>{<token type>}{<code>}` ([Pygments token types](http://pygments.org/docs/tokens/)).  For the `default` style, this is `\PYGdefault`.  For the patch to work, you need to set the style *before* patching, so that the style macros exist.  Pygments is treating `source` as a keyword, which would be `\PYGdefault{k}{source}`. The patch detects the literal text `source`, and switches from keyword (`k`) to name (`n`).

Note that this only works with `minted` 2.0+ (which you are using, since you have the `breaklines` option).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\usemintedstyle{default}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{%
  \let\originalPYGdefault\PYGdefault
  \renewcommand{\PYGdefault}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{k}%
     {\ifstrequal{#2}{source}%
       {\originalPYGdefault{n}{#2}}%
       {\originalPYGdefault{#1}{#2}}}%
     {\originalPYGdefault{#1}{#2}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[breaklines=true,tabsize=4,samepage,frame=none,fontsize=\footnotesize]{sql}
SELECT 
    schedule,
    cost
FROM 
    Schedule
WHERE
        source = 'x'
    AND
        destination = 'y';
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found that by removing `\AtBeginEnvironment` I can still use the `\sql{}` command I had initially (which keeps the rest of the code cleaner). Is that somehow bad practice?

Comment: @CamilStaps The `\AtBeginEnvironment` is just to limit the scope of the redefinitions. Removing it shouldn't usually cause any problems, and as you found, the definitions need to be more broadly available for your custom command.